# Type of questions to be asked here?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, asking-questions

I am a self learner. I took admission in a college for graduation (correspondence) in bsc after long time quitting school. I have several books on different topics of mathematics but I am unable to solve all the questions. You are saying that you are not going to answer questions which are direct copy of questions in the book. Then how this website is going to help me. Should I not ask you guys any Question?

Comment: Actually, a lot of users here like nothing more than to answer questions copied straight out of textbooks, assignments and tests, believing that it is too onerous to demand even an iota more. Chances are such questions _will_ get answered, just like [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1423189).

Comment: Note especially the answer: provide context.

Comment: I got it.  I think this website is going to help me a lot. Thanks